# «Некуда пойти на танцы или посмотреть фильм». Верно без запятой?

Tags: запятые

«Некуда пойти на танцы или посмотреть фильм». Верно без запятой перед «или»?

Comment: \Конечно верно./

Answer (score 1):

***Некуда пойти*** на танцы **или** **посмотреть** фильм.

Безлично-инфинитивное предложение с однородной инфинитивной частью. Запятая не ставится при наличии союза ИЛИ.